# Codeigniter flashdata not working in internet explorer and google chrome

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

Codeigniter flashdata not working in internet explorer and chrome but it is working on firefox.What could be the issue?.

In My controller:-

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('login_error','Your username or password is incorrect.');
redirect(base_url().'admin/login');
```

In My view

```
echo  '<span>'.$this->session->flashdata('login_error').'</span>';
```

In Chrome and ie i'm getting blank span whereas in firefox it is displaying flash data.

There are similar questions on the stack but i could not find any answer which are working.

Comment: Paste some code and we'll probably be able to help you out..

Comment: which version of ie btw?

Comment: are you storing the session in a cookie or into the database?

Comment: Also do you have GZIP (Compression) enabled in your config.php ?

Comment: @HasoKeric  I'm storing session in database. whats the use of GZIP?

Comment: An alternative solution could be in this post.

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/29114118/1226309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.There was some issue with ie and chrome cookie management.

I change the `'sess_cookie_name'` in config from `'ci_session'`  to `'cisession'`

and `sess_expiration` from `7200` to `84200` and it got fixed.

Comment: Just to keep in mind, the flashdata works better with a `refresh` redirection instead of `location`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by setting:

```
$config['sess_use_database']= FALSE;
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 84200;
```