# Codeigniter Flash data is not working 1 out of 10 time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a very strange issue, the Codeigniter's flash data is not available 1 out of 10 time. Most of the time it works but randomly it doesn't. So, someone could help me know what could be the reason for this.

**Controller Code**

```
public function set_pagelist(){
    $site_id = $this->input->get('site_id');
    $use_list = $this->input->get('use_list');
    if($use_list=="1"){
        $use_list = (int) $use_list;
    }
    $data = array("site_id" => $site_id,"page_list_option" => $use_list);
    $url_send = $this->api_url."set_pagelist_option";
    $str_data = json_encode($data);
    $request = sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
    $response = json_decode($request, true);
    $errors = $response['errors'];
    $response_message = $response['response_message'];
    if (isset($response_message) && isset($errors)) {
        if (trim($response_message) === "Value Set" && trim($errors) === "None") {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_message', '<p><div class="alert-box success"><span>success: </span>Value has been set successfully</div></p>');
            redirect("manage-domain");

        } elseif($response_message === "Error" && $errors === "Invalid Pagelist Option") {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_message', '<p><div class="alert-box error"><span>Error: </span>Invalid Pagelist Option</div></p>');
            redirect("manage-domain");
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_message', '<p><div class="alert-box error"><span>Error: </span>OOPS some error occurred</div></p>');
        redirect("manage-domain");
    }

}
```

**In view:**

`echo $this->session->flashdata('upload_message');`

Comment: Where is your code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve this using the following link [Codeigniter flashdata not working in internet explorer and google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184304/codeigniter-flashdata-not-working-in-internet-explorer-and-google-chrome)
Thought of sharing as it can be of any help to someone