# Can't log in to app via iFrame on Chrome, but can when viewed directly

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, iframe, authentication

I am building an auction app for a music festival and the app is being embedded into the festival's site via an `iFrame`.

The problem I'm having is with Chrome. When viewed [directly](http://lab.starchcreative.co/riff-auction/app/) (on the source site) I can log in to the app fine, but when viewing the app through the iFrame [on the festival's website](http://rifflandia.com/info/fun/war-child/war-child-auction/?beta=true) I can't seem to log in. However, *I can still register users*. I should also note that this system was built on CodeIgnitor.

I have absolutely no clue why this is happening? Does it have to do with cross-domain policies? Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your application working fine on other browsers??

Comment: Yes it works fine in Safari, Firefox, Opera, Chrome/Safari for iOS...

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907962/codeigniter-session-class-not-working-in-chrome/12911127#12911127) may be it would help you

Comment: I just created a simple iframe and was able to signup and login, I can't see the iframe you are using anymore on the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are interacting with probably has implemented a protection against [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). The protection usually includes either breaking out of iFrames or completely blocking all requests coming out of iFrames.

I would contact the site developer and inquire regarding any implemented clickjacking protections they have in place - they may be able to whitelist your domain name, but this depends on their technology etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem as the site developer knows of my application and has allowed it and implemented the iFrame code himself. Also this is Chrome-specific