# codeigniter iis error with session

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeignitor '2.0.2' with IIS (Internet Information server 7) and sql server 2005. when after logging and click the links on a page , it is automatically logged me out.any solution please.(this problem occurs when using windows server 2003).[my local machine it's working fine]

Comment: Probably the answer you are looking for is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907962/codeigniter-session-class-not-working-in-chrome - it has something to do with the difference of timezone

Comment: the server and client machines are in same country and same time zone

Comment: I have had couple issues with CodeIgniter's session as well. Just to make sure you didn't leave anything out, try printing out current date time (and timezone) from your server and see if it matches. It sounds to me that your session expired without you knowing it. Have you tried increasing the `sess_expiration` to something much bigger?

Comment: I tried but their is nothing with time zone or ajax requests. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you use $_SESSION for authentication , its possible problem from session directory .
check your PHP configuration , session path should be writable and also exist .

Comment: what if the requirements change to sqlserver 2008 and windows server 2008

Comment: I tried but their is nothing with time zone or ajax requests. Please help

Comment: its possible you have problem with setting cookies in your browser from server , check configuration file , it should be valid in path and domain ...