# Codeigniter 3.0.0: Session gone after redirecting to other page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have some problem, my codes is working normally, but the session is not.
here the codes :

```
public function index()
{
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
        $this->lm->username = $_POST['username'];
        $this->lm->password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT hakAkses, nip FROM user WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'",
              $this->lm->username,
              $this->lm->password
              );
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $query->row();
        $sessData = array('nip' => $row->nip,
                          'hakAkses' => $row->hakAkses);
        $this->session->set_userdata($sessData);
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

        if ($this->session->userdata('hakAkses') == 'ADMIN') {
            redirect('Admin/index','refresh');
        } else if ($this->session->userdata('hakAkses') == 'PENGAJAR'){         
            redirect('Pengajar/index','refresh');
        } else {
            redirect('Login','refresh');
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('Login/LoginView');
    }

}
```

That went well when i did it after set the session`$this->session->set_userdata($sessData);`. But when i try print again in other form the session has gone.

my session config :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessios';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

OK the reason is everytime i redirect page the session generate new session. 
how to handle this?

Comment: How you set your session? Can you post your code?

Comment: Did you set your session save path on config.php dont leave is NULL

Comment: This might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911127/1232366

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's not clear why . But possibly u forgot to load session from the other page . So Try auto load session library from autoload.php. Or use `$this->load->library('session');` in the controller.

Comment: i already autoload session in my config.php 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Comment: whats the output of vardump of session variable in the otherpage.?

Comment: it giving this array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1496306605) }

Comment: Since you are using driver database in config . You have to create session table . CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);

Comment: Refer here. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: Yes i alredy have table ci_sessions